TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of null
I am trying to use 'react-native-audio-record' to record audio in my app for streaming it to the backend. I am fairly new to this and im repeatedly getting an error that is
TypeError: cannot read property 'init' of null
const initialiseAudio = async () => {
    AudioRecord?.init({
      sampleRate: 44100,
      channels: 1,
      bitsPerSample: 16,
      audioSource: 6,
      wavFile: 'stream.wav',
    })
  } 

I have imported the library properly. and Ive set up permissions as well
Heres the full code
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { useState,useRef,useCallback, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Text, View , Button, StyleSheet , TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import {styled} from 'nativewind'
import PagerView from 'react-native-pager-view';

import {PermissionsAndroid, Platform} from 'react-native';
// fonts
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import AudioRecord from 'react-native-audio-record'

const StyledButton = styled(TouchableOpacity)
const StyledView = styled(View)
const StyledPagerView = styled(PagerView)

// preventing splashscreen from auto-hide
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {

  const initialiseAudio = async () => {
    AudioRecord?.init({
      sampleRate: 44100,
      channels: 1,
      bitsPerSample: 16,
      audioSource: 6,
      wavFile: 'stream.wav',
    })
  } 

  const requestMicrophone = async () => { 
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        try {
          const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO,
            {
              title: 'Audio Permissions',
              message: 'This app needs access to your microphone',
              buttonPositive: 'Allow',
              buttonNegative: 'Deny',
              buttonNeutral: 'Allow Later'
            },
          );
          if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            console.log('permission granted.. Seting up Libraries');
            console.log(AudioRecord)
            await initialiseAudio();
            
            console.log("initialised")
          } else {
            console.log('permission denied');
            return;
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.warn(err);
          return;
        }
      }
}




const [isStreaming, SetIsStreaming] = useState(false)


// const [displayText, setDisplayText] = useState("")

const [isLoaded] = useFonts(
  {
    "roboto": require("./assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"),
    "anton": require("./assets/fonts/Anton.ttf"),
    "oswald": require("./assets/fonts/Oswald-Bold.ttf")
  }
)


const handleOnLayout = useCallback(async () => {
  if (isLoaded) {
    await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    await requestMicrophone();
  }
}, [isLoaded]);

// just a final check 
if (!isLoaded){
  return null;
}

  // FRONT END
  return (
  <StyledPagerView className='flex-[1]' initialPage={0}>
  
    <StyledView key="1" onLayout={handleOnLayout} className="flex-[1] items-center bg-black grid grid-rows-3">

        <StyledView style={styles.shadowProp} className='flex h-[52vh] w-[97vw] rounded-[30px] 
        bg-white 
        grid grid-rows-2'>
            {/* info display area */}
            <StyledView className='flex justify-center items-center h-[50vh]'>
                  <Text style={{fontFamily: "oswald"}} className='text-[9vh]'>display</Text>
            </StyledView>

            <StyledView className='flex justify-center items-center h-20 mt-5'>
                <StyledView className='w-fit bg-orange-ui rounded-[30px]'>
                      <Text style={{fontFamily: "anton"}} className='text-xl p-3 text-white'>00 : 27 </Text>
                </StyledView>
            </StyledView>

        </StyledView>

        

        <StyledButton style={styles.shadowProp}
        
        className='flex justify-center items-center h-[15vh] w-[30vw] 
        rounded-full border-none bg-orange-ui mt-auto mb-[5vh]'>
          <Text style={{fontFamily: "anton"}} className="text-2xl text-white">{isStreaming ? 'Stop ' : 'Start ' }</Text>
        </StyledButton>
 
        <StatusBar style="auto" /> 
        
    </StyledView>

    {/* PAGE 2 */}
    <StyledView key="2" className="flex-[1] bg-white h-screen w-screen bg-black">
      <StyledView className='flex items-center grid grid-rows-2 h-screen w-screen bg-white'>
         <StyledView className='flex row h-[20vh] items-left justify-center w-screen bg-white'>
            <Text style={{fontFamily: "anton"}}  
            className='text-[5vh] p-3 mt-20 text-black'>Saved Sessions </Text>
         </StyledView>

         <StyledView className='flex row h-[100vh] items-center w-screen bg-black rounded-[45px]'>
            {/* list of sessions */}
            <StyledView className='flex h-[20vh] w-[90vw] bg-orange-ui rounded-[40px] m-5'>
                <StyledView className='flex rounded-full h-fit w-20 items-center bg-white m-4'>
                  <Text className='text-xl font'>S1 </Text>
                </StyledView>

                <StyledView className='flex rounded-full h-fit w-20 items-center bg-white m-4'>
                  <Text className='text-xl'>S1 </Text>
                </StyledView>
            </StyledView>

           
         </StyledView>
      </StyledView>
    </StyledView>

  </StyledPagerView>
  );
}

// custom styles (not nativewind)
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  shadowProp: {
    // for ios
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2},
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    // for android 
    elevation: 8
  },
 
})


I have even logged and found out that AudioRecord is not null and it shows:
 LOG  {"init": [Function anonymous], "on": [Function anonymous], "start": [Function anonymous], "stop": [Function anonymous]}

Also, im using expo go for developing it on my pixel 6a

I am facing the same issue. Were you able to figure it out?
